# Trying to get the tallest element but returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the tallest height of some elements using the following.

```
var blocks = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    blocks[i] = $('.blocks .block-' + i).outerHeight();
}

var tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, blocks);

console.log(tallest);
```

The heights are getting stored fine within the blocks array but when I output the tallest variable it's just coming up with NaN.

Comment: I guess, some elements may not be present in DOM, `blocks[i] = $('.blocks .block-' + i).outerHeight() || 0;` should fixed it

Comment: @Tushar `Math.max` can take a `null`, no problem there.

Comment: you have blocks[0] = undefined, use push instead `blocks.push($('.blocks .block-' + i).outerHeight())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `for` loop start with `1` instead of `0` so first element of array got undefined and tallest return `NaN`.

Instead of adding value to individual array element using `blocks[i]`. Use `push` for array.

```
var blocks = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    blocks.push($('.blocks .block-' + i).outerHeight() || 0);
}

var tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, blocks);

console.log(tallest);
```

Check snippet

```js
var blocks = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  blocks[i] = i;
}
var tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, blocks);
snippet.log('Using element : ' + blocks);
snippet.log('Using element tallest is : ' + tallest);

blocks = [];

for(var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    blocks.push(j);
}

tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, blocks);

snippet.log('Using push tallest element : ' + tallest);
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is 0 based - but the DOM is index from 1. Use `i - 1` as the array index and use `|| 0` when recording heights in to the array to prevent non-numeric values being added.

```
var blocks = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    blocks[i - 1] = $('.blocks .block-' + i).outerHeight() || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the problem with your code was the array you defined always had an undefined element in it thereby causing the max function to return NaN as output. In future, please make sure to define the array length you need.

```js
var blocks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  blocks[i] = $('.blocks-' + (i + 1)).height();
}

var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, blocks);

alert(tallest);
```

```css
        .blocks {
          width: 500px;
          height: 300px;
          border: 1px solid gray;
        }
        .blocks .blocks-1 {
          width: 150px;
          height: 100px;
          border: 1px solid red;
          float: left;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .blocks .blocks-2 {
          width: 150px;
          height: 200px;
          border: 1px solid orange;
          float: left;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .blocks .blocks-3 {
          width: 150px;
          height: 150px;
          border: 1px solid green;
          float: left;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-1">
  </div>
  <div class="blocks-2">
  </div>
  <div class="blocks-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your jQuery selector error, `.blocks .block-1` can select：

```
<div class='blocks'>
    <div class='block-1'>1</div>
    <div class='block-2'>2</div>
    <div class='block-3'>3</div>
</div>
```

But, I think you should want to meet two classes. Use:

```
blocks[i-1] = $('.blocks.block-' + i).outerHeight()||0;
```

Note：`$('.blocks.block-' + i)` has no spaces.